# How To Bind Data to excel in Office 365 web app

Tags: office365

I'm completely new to Office 365 Web App.I want to bind the data from database to excel in office 365.How to bind that data,please anybody provide me any sample code or links for binding data to the excel.

Thanks,

D Haraveer.

Answer (score 2):

```
function test(name) {
var result = "->";
try{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Service1.svc/GetData',
        contentType: 'xml',
        data: '{"value":' + name + '}',
        success: function (msg) {
            Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            result = "fail";
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    result = err.description;
}
return result;
```

}

By using wcf service you can achieve the task.Here you need to write jquery code for getting values from the database.Above sample code for binding values from database.

Comment: I am implementing a similar solution to perform RPC calls. Any idea why this might respond with an Access denied error, even when I have set crossDomain: true and $.support.cors = true? I have tried with all browsers (incl IE10) it works, but within Excel it throws an error. Is there a settings that I have to enable?